# reference collapsing with template template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, rvalue-reference, reference-collapsing

Why reference collapsing does not apply in

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class C>
void f(C<T> && x); // x declaration is an rvalue!
```

How can I perfect forward and how can I avoid overloading all combinations of const lvalue ref, lvalue ref, rvalue ref in

```
template<typename T> // not necessary a template template class here
void f(C<T>, C<T>, C<T>, ..., C<T>)
{
    // do something with T
    // move or copy arguments to a function
}
```

Comment: Reference collapsing only applies when the form is `T&&`. `C<T>&&` always designates an rvalue reference (like `std::vector<T>&&`)

Comment: @AndyProwl: Or when the form is `auto &&`.

Comment: @AndyProwl yep but without collapsing I can't solve the second question!

Comment: @Nawaz: Right, forgot about that

Comment: @a.lasram: If you need perfect forwarding let the form be `template<typename U> f(U&&)` and add a SFINAE-constraint saying that `U` must be an instantiation of `C<T>` for some `T`.

Comment: @AndyProwl yep it'll do it. Why don't you formulate your 2 comments + Nawas additions in an answer?

Comment: @a.lasram: Because I would have to elaborate on it in order to make it a decent answer and I don't have time right now :(

Comment: @AndyProwl "C<T>&& always designates an rvalue reference" yes but I don't see why the rules of T&& doesn't apply to C when C is template <template class>

Comment: @a.lasram: Because the Standard says so. Why does the Standard say so? I don't know :)

Comment: This is all such a mess. Bloody C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will ned to use some kind of SFINAE, unfortunately

```
template<typename T>
struct HasOneTypeParam : std::false_type { };

template<typename T, template<typename> class C>
struct HasOneTypeParam<C<T>> : std::true_type { };

template<typename ...T>
struct SlurpThemAll { typedef int type; };

template<typename ...T, 
  typename SlurpThemAll<
     bool[HasOneTypeParam<typename std::decay<T>::type>::value * 2 - 1]...
     >::type = 0>
void f(T &&... x);
```

Depending on what you actually want to do, you can require all of the `std::decay<T>::type` to be the same type with some more SFINAE hacks.